# regex to remove hashtag from string

Tags: php, regex

I have the following code with regex trying to remove the hashtag from a string:

```
$text = "#jualan #jualanku #bag #bandung #jakarta #olshop #olshopindo #olshopindonesia #trusted #trustedseller #trustedolshop #tas #tasbagus #goodquality #premium #premiumquality #trixie #trixie bag #baju #kaos #spandex #bestseller #trixiewardrobe \nBella top\n\nSize s m l\n\nIdr 99.000\n\nLine: merlinehadiwijaya";
$newCaption = preg_replace('/#(?=[\w-]+)/', '', preg_replace('/(?:#[\w-]+\s*)+$/', '', $text));
```

however it only removes the '#' and not the whole hashtag. What am I doing wrong in my regex?

I wanted the result to be:

```
\nBella top\n\nSize s m l\n\nIdr 99.000\n\nLine: merlinehadiwijaya
```

Comment: `#trixie bag #baju` but you have `bag` without hashtag, shouldn't your result be: `bag\nBella top\n\nSize s m l\n\nIdr 99.000\n\nLine: merlinehadiwijaya`, regardless this seems what you want `trim(preg_replace('/#\S+\s*/', '', $text));`?

Answer (score 4):

You are first using a Positive Lookahead assertion which only **asserts** that the specified characters follow the preceding pound sign, which is the reason only the pound sign is being removed from the input string. Secondly you are trying to use cascading `preg_replace()` calls which is not necessary. You could simply do this in one call ...

```
$newCaption = preg_replace('/#\S+ */', '', $text);
```

**Note:** You have `bag` without a preceding hashtag as well, so this will also be retained in the result.

Output

```
bag 
Bella top

Size s m l

Idr 99.000

Line: merlinehadiwijaya
```

[<kbd>**Code Demo**</kbd>](https://eval.in/208151)